# Link preview Chrome extension, like Safari's

Tags: web-browser, chrome, hyperlink

Safari has a [feature](https://appleinsider.com/articles/15/04/28/os-x-tips-preview-links-in-safari-with-a-three-finger-tap) that lets you three-finger tap to preview a link. When you tap on the link, the referenced website pops up so that you can quickly scan it and decide whether you want to commit to opening it. This is especially useful when going through search results, but also when you're reading an article and want to see what is linked. If you then click on the pop up, a new tab opens for that website; if, instead, you click elsewhere, the pop-up closes.

**I am looking for an extension for the same functionality in Chrome.**

Over the years, many people have asked about this: most recently, [this one on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/guvv4m/extension_that_gives_you_the_ability_to_preview/).

The options that I've seen tend to give a *summary card* rather than just showing the website. This leads to the problem that not all sites are supported, because the extension doesn't know how to summarize every site. I am looking for an extension that simply shows the website in a pop up.

The most commonly suggested option is the apparently defunct [ezLinkPreview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ezlinkpreview-modal/ogmljbopmblcfhknligfhgfjjfaigkll?hl=en). [Link Preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/preview-any-link-anywhere/idalccinfigpohjpehkcdcpgnannhhfl?hl=en) got a hold of the obvious name, but only gives a summary card, and seems to believe I'd want the pop ups to stay open ... like new windows ... (that feature exists already ...). [Link-Preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-preview/giplmolhikmggbhmliaighboilflkfph?hl=en) adds a hyphen but not much functionality.

Does anyone know of a Chrome extension (or an Automation even?) that lets me

1. preview a link in Chrome so that I can
2. see the original website
3. in a pop up
4. that will close when I click elsewhere